# Is there a way for fill in the tidyr complete function to vary?

Tags: r, tidyr

My dataset has information on the proportions of individuals of different age classes. I'm using complete to add in NA values for the proportion when that age was not documented in a given year.

Additionally, consecutive years of data are denoted by a seg value (e.g., 1988-1993 are seg = 1, and 1998-2003 are seg = 2). I do not want the missing years completed.

```
df <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                      levels = "A", class = "factor"), 
                     year = c(1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
                              1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 
                              1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 
                              2003, 2003, 2003), 
                     age = c(`9104` = 1, `9341` = 2, `9292` = 1, `9632` = 2, `9960` = 4, 
                             `9543` = 1, `9857` = 3, `9685` = 1, `9968` = 2, `10169` = 3, 
                             `9858` = 1, `10127` = 2, `10212` = 3, `10009` = 1, `10284` = 2, 
                             `10522` = 6, `10464` = 1, `10605` = 2, `10830` = 3, `10556` = 1, 
                             `10744` = 2, `11056` = 3, `10687` = 1, `11061` = 2, `11279` = 5, 
                             `10912` = 1, `11109` = 2, `11197` = 3, `11065` = 1, `11194` = 2, 
                             `11154` = 1, `11255` = 2, `11324` = 3), 
                     pAGE = c(0.972, 0.028, 0.964, 0.005, 0.031, 0.823, 0.177, 0.921, 0.074, 
                              0.004, 0.846, 0.045, 0.109, 0.833, 0.155, 0.012, 0.927, 0.054, 
                              0.019, 0.784, 0.21, 0.005, 0.958, 0.017, 0.025, 0.852, 0.124, 
                              0.024, 0.913, 0.087, 0.909, 0.073, 0.019), 
                     seg = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyr)
df %>%
  complete(year, nesting(site), age, fill = list(seg = 999))
```

Is there a way to change `fill = list(seg = 999)` so that the seg = 1 in the same years that seg is already 1 and the same for seg = 2? Sometime like `fill = list(seg = lag(seg)`.

Comment: `df %>% complete(year, nesting(site), age)%>%fill(seg)`

Comment: Perfect! If you want to put this in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Question edited to indicate that `complete` is a `tidyr` function, not `dplyr`.